# Copy data from a table, into the same table with a different key

Tags: sql, ingres

I was curious if it was possible to take data from a table, and duplicate it but assign a new primary key

for example, I wish to take data that has a column "question_id" which acts as the unique key for the table, and copy all of the data from the table with that question_id to the same table but with a new question_id.

any thoughts as to if this is possible using SQL?

my database is an ingres database

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, but what database is this for?

Comment: its for an ingres database.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (Question_Id, OtherField,...)
SELECT SomeNewQuestionId, OtherField,...
FROM YourTable
WHERE Question_Id = SomeQuestionId
```

Just replace `SomeQuestionId` and `SomeNewQuestionId` with the appropriate values.

Comment: ok so for this. the insert statement is my new data i want, then my select statement is from the old data, and in the where clause i must make question_id= my old question_ID and SomeQuestion_ID= new question_ID.

Comment: @John -- sounds right.  See this fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d31b/1 -- Best regards.

Comment: the fiddle will help me a lot. now if my new question_id is already generated (its the pregenerated question set number for the person) what would that look like.

Comment: I did this..
'code'
CREATE TABLE YourTable (Question_Id int, OtherField varchar(10));

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (1, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (2, 'bugger');
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (3, '');

INSERT INTO YourTable (Question_Id, OtherField)
SELECT 3, OtherField
FROM YourTable
WHERE Question_Id = 1
'code'

and it generated 2 rows with 3 as the question ID. however i want to overwrite row 3 with the data provided.

Comment: sorry if this is confusing. in the SQL fiddle it makes 2 rows with question_id = 3, one with null data and one with 'hello'. i want to overwrite where question_id=3 with the info from row 1.

Comment: That sounds more like an `UPDATE` -- here's one approach: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24cb5/1 -- Please note, this is Database Specific so depending on which database you're using, this may or may not work.  You can also look into using `MERGE` if there will be updates and inserts.  Good luck!

Comment: ok,I will have to play around with it.. thank you so very much for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple select query.

```
insert into mytable
 (field2, field3, etc)
select field2, field3, etc
from mytable
where whatever.
```

This assumes that neither fields 2 nor 3 are the primary key, and that you have an autoincrement table.

Comment: well my table has the new question_ID already generated. so i want to take the old data, and copy it to the row with the pre-generated question_id

Answer (score 2):

Fast forward two years.... :)
I think this is the best and simplest way to do this.  Inserting a row of data from the same table with a primary key will result in error because primary keys are unique for each row: Let question_id = 100.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM MyTable Where question_id=100;
```

In PostgreSQL:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "MyTable_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (question_id)=(100) already exists.
```

It is very simple to avoid the duplicate key value:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT (SELECT MAX(question_id)+1),Column1,Column2,etc FROM MyTable Where question_id=100;
```

By using MAX(question_id)+1, you are incrementing the maximum value of MyTable's question_id primary key, then add/copy the data to a new row with a unique question_id value.